# Dependency issues while installing PacketTracer

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, 20.04

I couldn't install PacketTracer on my Ubuntu 20.04 using `sudo dpkg -i PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb` command.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Download and install the other (dependency) package first.

Answer (score 0):

as it said you need to install packets it depends on

```
sudo apt-get install qt-at-spi
```

however if it depends on something else you should install it too...

it seems it is only on xenial and bionic 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/qt-at-spi

However you can compile it from git maybe :

https://salsa.debian.org/a11y-team/qt-at-spi

or there maybe any other package it can satisfy the requirement ...

Try to contact with the coder of packettracer ...